# What registry changes an activity makes

Tags: windows-registry

I would like to be able to analyse what changes an activity / program makes.  The idea is to take a snapshot before and after the code is run.

What I need is the ability to generate a registry-importable file that reflects all new / modified registry entries.

Free would be my preferred choice :-).

Thanks

Comment: So, what did your research turn up so far? Have you tried to google your question? What problems did you encounter when using methods you could find? (And if you're willing to use this method to install software, it's not going to work. Google for "unattended" or "silent" installation instead.)

Comment: See my answer to the dupe question :)

Comment: @gronostaj: I found a number of products that do this comparison action but I could not find any that generates a reg file that can be imported.

Comment: @DavidPostill: the original answer is practically identical to mine :-)